# CodeIgniter 3 Implement Promise

Tags: php, angularjs, codeigniter, promise

My CI app makes API call to third party Rest API server which will be consumed by the front end. At first, front end app will hit my CI app and which in turn will hit the third party `LogInAPI`(session valid for 15 mins), and after login, we need to hit subsequent API calls by passing the key(response of `loginApi`) in the header. So basically I need to hit `loginAPI` for every 15 minutes. I am trying angular promise kinda approach in my Codeigniter app don't know how to achieve it? what is the best way to do it to prevent the front end from receiving empty or session expired response?

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to keep refreshing that login. Create time stamp when You receive login from 3rd party API. Then pass it to back end on each request.

On the back end on each call from front end check time stamp, if it's expired do not do normal calls to API but first get the new login, then do requested calls.

As response to each front end call return also login info, so that front end gets's new credentials after renewal.

If credentials are app wide, then front end does not have to be aware of them at all. Just store credentials in some kind of storage (SQL DB, key value store, etc.), and do auto renewals when appropriate.

Comment: great idea, also instead of passing timestamp to and fro for each request you can create a cookie entry which will deleted after 15 min so before requesting to api you can check if cookie exist if not proceed for login as per the answer

Comment: Is there any way to achieve this in PHP CI rather than calling login API from  front end

Comment: @PsycheGenie yes, look at my last paragraph. Whatever code calls external API can check for timestamps, and make decision to first reacquire new credentials, and only then call main api.

Comment: @przemo_li can you explain that in detail? Imagine I am hitting userDetail API during my session expired. then I need to hit login api after renewing session and then again same userDetail API need to be hitted.

Comment: @PsycheGenie You can compute if session expired! That's the trick. You do not send userDetail call unless You have valid session, if you computed that session is expired You send login call first. Is that clearer?